# D3 linechart string domain x-axis

Tags: d3.js, axis, linechart, ordinal

I'm relatively new to D3, and I can't figure out why something isn't working.
I want to draw a line-chart with d3, and this works fine, but I have problems with the axes.

With the following code it goes wrong somewhere and I don't see how to solve...

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
.range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.age; }));
```

If `d.age` is an integer (like `1;2;3` etc.), it works well. But I want strings on the x-axis. Like `("netherlands", "England", "Belgium")`.

So if `d.age` is an integer it draws the graph OK, if d.age is a string it doesn't draw anything.

I have also tried instead of linear to use ordinal, but this gave an incorrect chart. (Weird looking lines...).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to use categorical values on an axis, you need a categorical (ordinal) scale. Have a look at [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales). Your code would look something like

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.country; }));
```

Note that this uses `map` to extract the string values -- this may or may not be implemented in your particular browser, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more details.

Comment: Thanx for you reaction, I knew I needed an ordinal scale, but this gave such a weird chart.. (looping lines etc). But I used range instead of rangeRoundBands. So this solved the problem, (now I have only a little problem that the points and the xaxis aren't on the same level. (there's some shift visible)).

Comment: I was wondering why use rangeRoundBands instead of rangeBands? Seems like it avoids antialiasing artifacts, but not sure if there was another reason you used it. Thanks.

Comment: That's the only reason.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, width]);
```

Here is Fiddle Link
http://jsfiddle.net/sk2Cf/

Comment: thanks for your reaction. It was already solved with the solution above, but this solution you provided also worked. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't imagine a more elegant solution.

Comment: I just found this question and tried the fiddle, but it has the same problem as I currently have in my code: The x-position of the graph is not the same as the x-position of the x-scale labels. You can see it better if you remove the interpolation. The x-position of the line is where the top-left position of a bar would be if it were a bar chart.